# How to find xpath of a parent div based on multiple children divs?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

Consider this html for example

```
<div class="randomclass-parent" id="Need to find this div">  // Parent Div I am looking for
<table class="rando table">
<tbody role="presentation">
<tr role="presentation">
<td id="radnom">
<div class="childclass">Sam</div>
<td id="radnom">
<div class="childclass">Elliot</div>
<td id="radnom">
<div class="childclass">Smith</div>

</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Now, I know that the parent div contains a `table` which contains multiple table rows, which in turn contain table data tag, which contains the div with some text that I know beforehand. I want to be able to do something like this. Not sure what is the syntax for it.

```
String xpathofParentDiv=Parent div which contains "//div[contains(text(),'Sam')] and //div[contains(text(),'Elliot')] and //div[contains(text(),'Smith')]";
```

How do i go about locating the parent div, based on the text in the children divs located inside the table data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following `xpath`

```
//div[.//div[text()='Sam'] and .//div[text()='Elliot'] and .//div[text()='Smith']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Parent is a method used to retrieve the parent node of the current node

I hope this is what you lookin for-

Xpath= //*[text()='Sam']//parent::div